# Copy to Clipboard function for multiple buttons how to switch from id to class identifier

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, clipboard, copy-paste

I need some help please i have a nice copy to clipboard function which works well for ids and only one button on website.
But I need it to be done for multiple buttons and multiple values with class identifier i think but i really got no idea how to switch/change it from id identifier to class identifier and make it work for multiple buttons and inputs on one page.
Could you please help me?

This is my HTML button with ID identifier which i need for class to make it work for multiple buttons:

```
<button type="submit" id="bbcopyButton" class="btn btn-md btn-primary-filled btn-form-submit">BB Code copy</button>
```

This is the Input to copy from also by ID but i need to make it work with Class in order to copy more values from different input types:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="bbcopyTarget" value="valueno.1" name="name" readonly="readonly" onclick="focus();select();">
```

I hope you understand what i want

Here is finally the Javascript Code which should be switched into class identifier in order to copy several/multiple values on one page:

```
document.getElementById("bbcopyButton").addEventListener("click", function() {

    copyToClipboardMsg(document.getElementById("bbcopyTarget"), "bbcopyButton");

});

function copyToClipboardMsg(elem, msgElem) {
    var succeed = copyToClipboard(elem);
    var msg;
    if (!succeed) {
        msg = "Press Ctrl+c to copy"
    } else {
        msg = "BB Code copied <i class='lnr lnr-thumbs-up'></i>"
    }
    if (typeof msgElem === "string") {
        msgElem = document.getElementById(msgElem);
    }
    msgElem.innerHTML = msg;
    msgElem.style.background = "green";
    msgElem.style.border = "2px solid green";

    setTimeout(function() {
        msgElem.innerHTML = "BB Code copy";
        msgElem.style.background = "";
        msgElem.style.border = "";

    }, 2000);
}



function copyToClipboard(elem) {
    // create hidden text element, if it doesn't already exist
    var targetId = "_hiddenCopyText_";
    var isInput = elem.tagName === "INPUT" || elem.tagName === "TEXTAREA";
    var origSelectionStart, origSelectionEnd;
    if (isInput) {
        // can just use the original source element for the selection and copy
        target = elem;
        origSelectionStart = elem.selectionStart;
        origSelectionEnd = elem.selectionEnd;
    } else {
        // must use a temporary form element for the selection and copy
        target = document.getElementById(targetId);
        if (!target) {
            var target = document.createElement("textarea");
            target.style.position = "absolute";
            target.style.left = "-9999px";
            target.style.top = "0";
            target.id = targetId;
            document.body.appendChild(target);
        }
        target.textContent = elem.textContent;
    }
    // select the content
    var currentFocus = document.activeElement;
    target.focus();
    target.setSelectionRange(0, target.value.length);

    // copy the selection
    var succeed;
    try {
        succeed = document.execCommand("copy");
    } catch(e) {
        succeed = false;
    }
    // restore original focus
    if (currentFocus && typeof currentFocus.focus === "function") {
        currentFocus.focus();
    }

    if (isInput) {
        // restore prior selection
        elem.setSelectionRange(origSelectionStart, origSelectionEnd);
    } else {
        // clear temporary content
        target.textContent = "";
    }
    return succeed;
}
```

Some help would be great.
Thanks.

I will make it a little bit clearer when i have a second button with same ID the  Javascript/JQuery Code does nothing and cant point to second input value
This would be the second Button:

```
<button type="submit" id="bbcopyButton" class="btn btn-md btn-primary-filled btn-form-submit">BB Code copy</button>
```

And the second input where i want to copy from:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="bbcopyTarget" value="valueno.2" name="name" readonly="readonly" onclick="focus();select();">
```

Hope this helps to understand better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this code:

```
var but = document.getElementsByClassName('btn btn-md btn-primary-filled btn-form-submit');
var txt = document.getElementsByClassName('form-control');

for (let x=0; x < but.length; x++){
    but[x].addEventListener("click", function() {
        copyToClipboardMsg(txt[x], but[x]);
    }, false);
}
```

Instead of:

```
document.getElementById("bbcopyButton").addEventListener("click", function() {

    copyToClipboardMsg(document.getElementById("bbcopyTarget"), "bbcopyButton");

});
```

This will only work if number of buttons = number of txt fields. If you want to avoid using `let` then you need to change it like this:

```
var but = document.getElementsByClassName('btn btn-md btn-primary-filled btn-form-submit');
var txt = document.getElementsByClassName('form-control');
for (var x = 0; x < but.length; x++) {
  (function(x) {
    but[x].addEventListener("click", function() {
      copyToClipboardMsg(txt[x], but[x]);
    }, false);
  })(x);
}
```